# c# Xamarin Forms ContentPage - Gap on Top

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This would seem to be really simple (and probably is), but I just can't seem to find any information about this.

Take a look at:
[image]

**There is a full width white gap on top.  What is it?  How do I get rid of it or access it (add text, buttons, icons, etc)?**

For this test, my code is super simple. xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
     x:Class="TestApp.TestPage">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0">
        <maps:Map x:Name="TestMap" IsShowingUser="true" MapType="Street" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

    namespace Test
    {
        public partial class TestPage : ContentPage
        {
            public TestPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        }
    }
```

app.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
        <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="Black"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="DefaultPageStyle" TargetType="ContentPage">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Edit: The comment from @Vulcan Lee, sent me on a path to finding the missing (key) information.**

Which was, inside App.xaml.cs, I had:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new TestPage());
}
```

So, this has to do with the navigation menu.  **How do I access, format or remove it?**

Comment: What device or emulator are you using to test, that the screenshot came from?

Comment: @Brian Mains: This screen shot is from Genymotion.  But trying with one of the default emulators shows basically the same thing.

Comment: I copy your super simple. xaml and run on emulator, that is no any space. You can see following 2 emulator screen capture.

http://xamarindoggy.azurewebsites.net/Content/map1.png

http://xamarindoggy.azurewebsites.net/Content/map2.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white space is actually navigation bar.

Change this:

`new NavigationPage(new TestPage())`

to

`new TestPage()`

Or just remove the navigation bar if you still want to make the first page as a navigation page:

`NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`

I remember this change is introduced in Xamarin.Forms 2.3.x.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the map to `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"`. It will not have much effect on the `StackLayout` because the `StackLayout` just wants to be what ever size it's children are. If setting the map's `VerticalOptions` does not work, you could instead set it's `HeightRequest` property manually.

If all that fails, I would suggest putting the map into a `Grid` instead.